# Object's function getting called while sending data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, object

Sending a plain javascript object with function via AJAX request results in invoking this function. 
Why is that happening? 
The problem does not occur when sending JSON data. 
What is the best way to convert that object to JSON?

I enclose sample code that presents this behaviour.

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    A.prototype.getValue = function () {
        console.log('getValue');
        return this.value;
    };
    return A;
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = new A(10);

    var xhr = $.ajax("http://example.com/", {
        data: a,
        type: 'post',
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });
}
```

Output of the code is:

```
getValue
success
```

Comment: wouldn't `new A(10);` execute that function ?

Comment: Oh, wait! No it wouldn't, but why would you send a function with ajax, what are you expecting to get from that ?

Comment: jQuery needs to serialize the object, but I'm not sure why that would cause `getValue` to be called.

Comment: I don't want it to be sent, that is the problem. I thought $.ajax function would handle that automatically.

Comment: Handle what exactly? Convert what to JSON? You have a new instance of a function, and you're expecting to get what ?

Comment: Strip the object of it's functions - actually I didn't know I was also passing those functions.

Comment: Why not use `data: a.getValue()`? Isn't that the point of defining a function that lets you get the value?

Comment: If there was a function x() { console.log('x'); } is still would be called. Imagine that A had stored more values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `jQuery.param` (used internally by `jQuery.ajax`) uses the *return value* of a function when serializing the request parameters. [From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

> As of jQuery 1.3, the return value of a function is used instead of the function as a String.

Thus, when `jQuery.param` encounters your `a` object and sees the `getValue` property being a function, it calls the function and uses the (serialized) the return value.

Either way, why would you want to pass such a complex object as request data? If you don't want to pass that function along with the request data, you're better off creating a custom serialization function for your `A` class, such as:

```
A.prototype.serialize = function() {
    return { value: this.value };
}
```

and use that instead:

```
var xhr = $.ajax("http://example.com/", {
    data: a.serialize(),
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That is the answer I have been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Kronkiel I updated my answer. I'd suggest you add a function to create a "stripped down" object which can be safely passed to `jQuery.param`. You can still let jQuery do the conversion between the plain object and the request parameter string.